# Creating this function template

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a simple class template with tuples of vectors:

```
template <typename... T>
struct TupleOfVectors {
  std::tuple<std::vector<T>...> tuple;
};
```

I can use it like this:

```
TupleOfVectors<double, std::string> tuple;

auto vec0 = std::get<0>(tuple.tuple);
vec0.push_back(1.2);

auto vec1 = std::get<1>(tuple.tuple);
vec1.push_back("foo");
```

I want to encapsulate this into the class template itself. This is how I'd really like to use my class template:

```
tuple.vec<0>.push_back(1.2);
tuple.vec<1>.push_back("foo");
```

How do I develop such a `vec()` template member function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct TupleOfVectors {
    std::tuple<std::vector<Ts>...> tuple;

    template< size_t N >
    auto vec() -> decltype( std::get<N>(tuple) ) {
        return std::get<N>(tuple);
    }

};

TupleOfVectors<int, short, double, float> t;

t.vec<3>().push_back( 3.14f );
```